# Can't create UIImage with [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] and file is there

Tags: ios, file, uiimage

I have google this question, most use a wrong method:[UIImage imageNamed:]. I am not. and I sure the  file is existed. The follow code is run on iOS8.1.

```
        self.cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
        UIImage *avatorImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:headCGImage];
        NSString *avatorName = [[[NSUUID alloc] init] UUIDString];
        avatorName = [avatorName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
        avatorName = [self.cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:avatorName];
        NSData *avatorImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(avatorImage);
        BOOL writeSuccess = [avatorImageData writeToFile:avatorName atomically:YES];
        if (!writeSuccess)
           NSLog(@"Write to File Error");
        //read file form other place, it's just nil.
        UIImage *imageFromFile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForImage];
```

then I use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] to get a UIImage. There is a strange thing. When I run app first time, all works. But I stop app, and run it again, [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] return just a nil. I don't know why.

---------------------------I am a cute line---------------------------

Summery:begin in iOS8, directory from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) is no longer be same every time you app run. That's why my code works first time run and not works after. Thanks for Midhun MP.

Ref: [Changes to App Containers in iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)

Comment: How did you retrieving the image back?

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]

Comment: That I got from your question. I asked how did you pass the file name and how did you create that

Comment: Em, actually, I use Core Data to store my data. A entity's property is a NSString, I assign the path string to this property, then fetch this entity at some place, use someEntity.pathForBackup to get path for image, then use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:], path like this:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5A70DE99-6F63-4592-898D-15289BADE9DE/Documents/CF7DFDB8-0A5D-4C13-9DFE-1C6C96B59DDA.png

Comment: You can't get the image in that way. You don't need to keep whole path in the core data. Instead save the file name and calculate the path at run-time.

Comment: why this way does't work??? Is app folder not always 5A70DE99-6F63-4592-898D-15289BADE9D‌​E?It changes when run app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comments, you are saving the whole path in your core-data and trying to load the image using that path.

In latest iOS version that 36 character folders are changing each time when we close and open the app.

So instead of saving the whole path, only save the file name and retrieve it using:

**Objective C**

```
NSString *yourImageName = @"CF7DFDB8-0A5D-4C13-9DFE-1C6C96B59DDA.png"; // Replace with actual image name
NSString *docDirPath    = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *pathForImage  = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourImageName];
UIImage *imageFromFile  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForImage];
```

**Swift:**

```
var yourImageName = "CF7DFDB8-0A5D-4C13-9DFE-1C6C96B59DDA.png";
var docDir        = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var docDirPath    = docDir[0] as? String
var pathForImage  = docDirPath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(yourImageName)
var imageFromFile = UIImage(contentsOfFile: pathForImage)
```

You can find the details here [Technical Note TN2406:
Changes To App Containers In iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. I change code as you say, it works!

Comment: I search in the documentation and not find note about this, where do you find this?

Comment: @DeveloperYe: Actually from the beginning of iOS itself, when you update an app the location name will change. In iOS 8 it is changing each run, you can just check your simulator folder by just printing.

Comment: @DeveloperYe: I found it here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html

Comment: Oh, it comes from the practice. I has not file programming practice before, and can't find it out. Apple should note it in documentation for developer, not just new developer like me. Thanks for you, this problem waste much time.

Comment: Oh, you hit in my face. I feel shame for this, hahahahaha

Comment: @DeveloperYe: It's Ok, don't worry. Everyone starts like this ;)

Comment: Could you provide a swift answer?  I am struggling to translate.